# how to stop a flash animation that is looping endlessly

Tags: actionscript-2

I already put a stop at a keyframe but the script still goes on and is not accepted via yahoo

I also tried stop() but it did not work, it is used to repeat a symbol and burst it

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;

var maxXPosition:Number = Stage.width/2;
var maxYPosition:Number = Stage.height/2;
var starCount:Number = 0;
var starIndex:Number = 0;
var starCreatorInterval:Number = null;

//Minimum and Maximum speeds.
//The speed defines the direction too, so the "minSpeed" must be negative.
var minSpeed = -3;
var maxSpeed =  12;

//Maximum number of stars on the screen at the same time.
var maxStarsOnScreen:Number = 500;

//Star creation speed (in miliseconds).
//For small movies, set a faster creation speed, so you will have more stars.
var creationSpeed = 10;

initStarfield();

/**
 * Space Warp Functions
 */
function initStarfield():Void {
    starCreatorInterval = setInterval(this, "generateStar", creationSpeed);
}

function generateStar():Void {
    updateMaximus();

    if (starCount < maxStarsOnScreen) {

        var xSpeed:Number = getRandom(minSpeed, maxSpeed);
        var ySpeed:Number = getRandom(minSpeed, maxSpeed);

        var mcStar:MovieClip = this.attachMovie("mcStar", "mcStar" + starIndex, starIndex, {_x: xSpeed * 5, _y: ySpeed * 5});
                mcStar.xSpeed = xSpeed;
                mcStar.ySpeed = ySpeed;
                mcStar._xscale = mcStar._yscale = 10;
                mcStar.onEnterFrame = function():Void { updateStar(this); }

        //Update control vars
        starCount++;
        starIndex++;

        if (starIndex > 500) starIndex = 500;
    }
}

function updateStar(mcStar:MovieClip):Void {
    if (mcStar._x > maxXPosition  || mcStar._y > maxYPosition  ||
            mcStar._x < -maxXPosition || mcStar._y < -maxYPosition ||
            mcStar._alpha < 5) {
        removeMovieClip(mcStar);
        starCount--;
    }
    else {
        mcStar._x += mcStar.xSpeed;
        mcStar._y += mcStar.ySpeed;
        if (mcStar._xscale < 100) mcStar._xscale = mcStar._yscale += 0.5;
        else mcStar._alpha -= 2;
    }
}

function updateMaximus():Void {
    maxXPosition = Stage.width/1;
    maxYPosition = Stage.height/1;
}

function getRandom(min:Number, max:Number):Number {
    var now:Date = new Date();
    var rand:Number = Math.random() * now.getMilliseconds() * 1000;
    var randReturn:Number = 0;

    randReturn = (rand % max) + min;

    if ((Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) % 2) == 0) randReturn *= -1;

    return randReturn;
    stop();
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Lovely animation. Does this snippet satisfies you?

```
_root.onMouseDown = function() {
    clearInterval(starCreatorInterval) ; 
};
```

add it to the end of your script and try it. By a click on stage, the interval variable will be deleted.